# HBase's Bytes.toBytes - is its output ordinal?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, decimal, ieee-754

I'm using `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes.toBytes(T)`. I'm storing the output of this function in a value in HBase and then I'd like to use comparison operations on it (`CompareOp.GREATER`, `CompareOp.LESS`...).

Does the output of `Bytes.toBytes(T)` maintain "comparability" for these types? Meaning, for `double` for example:

```
double d1 = ..., d2 = ...;
Bytes.compare(Bytes.toBytes(d1), Bytes.toBytes(d2)) == Double.compare(d1, d2)
```

Does this hold true for these types?

1. `float`/`double`
2. `int`/`long`
3. `String`
4. `BigDecimal`

Comment: Why does the word 'ordinal' appear in your title?

Answer (score 2):

If you convert back to the Java data-type before comparing, then yes. HBase stores binary data. If you cast this binary to a Java data type, the output value will be the same as the input value and the `compare` function will compare the values decoded as the appropriate data type.

If you use `Bytes.compare`, then this does not necessarily hold true because the values are compared based on their binary order, not based on their decoded value.

Notably, BigDecimal is not a primitive data-type, but a class that has two components:

> an arbitrary precision integer unscaled value and a 32-bit integer scale.

Depending on the exact binary encoding, the `Bytes.compare` results probably won't match `BigDecimal.compare` because the Bytes function compares raw binary data while BigDecimal compares the decoded values.

Similarly for `int` comparison. Negative int have a sign bit of `1` while positive int has a sign bit of `0`. Thus `Bytes.compare` will treat negative numbers as being larger than positive numbers.